# Facebook App Invite not show notification?

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-studio, facebook-graph-api

I have integrate Facebook App Invite to my app and the invitation has been sent to the recipient but there is no notification appear.

I tested with a new account and also uninstall app from my device but no luck here (my app on facebook in live mode and have unique namspace).

Are there anyone can help me to solve the problem with notification with App Invite, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing it under https://www.facebook.com/games/activity ?

Comment: Yes, the invitation appear in App Invite but I cannot get notification

Comment: Have you found any solution?